# JS not working due to invalid SSL Certificate, when user changes his system date

Tags: php, javascript, ssl, cross-domain

When a user logs in to my website, I redirect him to a https:// URL. (https://www.gruppenunterkuenfte.de/anbieter-bereich.html?next=/#einloggen)

If the user has set a wrong date on his machine (one year in the past), the certificate is considered invalid, for it is issued with a start of January 3rd 2012.

With this invalid certificate Safari and Chrome then seam to block scripts that load from external sources. (For example: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js), which causes the login to not function.

Now my question is, what would be a good solution to this problem?

1. Send the servers date in the JS-code and compare it with JS to the users current time. If it differs more than 24h, show the user a warning to set his date correctly. But that could be annoying for users... And maybe they don't have privileges to change it.
2. Don't load JS files from external domains. Then the certificate would still be invalid, but the page would function. However I prefer loading the scripts from ajax.googleapis.com for performance reasons.
3. Would it be possible to get a certificate, that is valid with whatever date the user has set?
4. Any other solutions I did not think of?

Comment: Is this really an issue? I mean, how many users have their system date set wrong? Finding a solution might not be worth the investment imo.

Comment: Well, my boss has, that's the problem :-) I think its due to some applications license being expired if the date is the current one.

Comment: so solution 1 is ruled out. You're right about 2, keep loading from google CDN. About 3, don't think you can get a cert without start date, or date prior the current one. So 4 is: tell your boss to renew his licenses =)

Comment: Respectfully, your boss should have the integrity to either *pay for his/her software* (if the license requires) or stop using it.  If this isn't an option, you have bigger problems than an incorrect date.

Comment: @Conrad Shultz: I fully agree. Though I don't know if thats the reason for sure. Its just the only thing I can think of why one might want to have an old system date. Still it could be that there are more users out there that set an old system date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could do #1 (pre-HTTPS) if you really wanted to, but as dirkbonhomme indicates, it's probably not worth the effort.

As for the rest.... DON'T DO THEM!

For #2, if they load a page with an invalid certificate, all bets are off for security.  Why bother with encryption at all?  Plus you are training your users to just click through security warnings, which degrades overall Internet security.  People are already **way** too willing to blindly accept what pop-up windows tell them.  This behavior then facilitates security compromises, malware distribution, etc.

For #3, no, not as far as I know.  And you wouldn't want this.  The notion of an expiring certificate is important to the integrity of the certificate signing system.  Since most people don't update their CRLs (and, inexplicably, most browsers don't seem to do this automatically), checking cert expiration is the last line of defense against certificates that might have been stolen or otherwise compromised.  It puts an upper bound on how long such certs can remain active in the wild.

For #4... the correct solution is for the user to fix their broken machine.  A great many schemes depend on accurate time, and the user should know that things will break if the time isn't updated properly.  If this is a recurring problem for your user base, maybe introduce them to a little something called [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).